# Handle api response before committing next mutation

Tags: javascript, vue.js, asynchronous, vuex

When my Vue app is created I call the requestUserProfile action. My objective here is to get the api call from `"/api/user/"` and set the data to the state before I call the setUserProfile mutation.

The problem here is that after I get the api response the setUserProfile mutation gets called before I've even set the data to the state. Is it possible to execute requestUserInfo fully before setUserProfile gets triggered?

This is the code I'm working with:

```
state() {
    return {
        requestUser: null,
        profile: null
    }
},
mutations: {
    setUserInfo (state) {
        apiService("/api/user/")
        .then(data => {
            state.requestUser = data["username"]
        })
    },
    setUserProfile (state) {
        let endpoint = "api/profile/";

        if (state.requestUser) {
            apiService(endpoint)
            .then(data => {
                state.profile = data
            })
        }
    }
},
actions: {
    async requestUserInfo ({ commit }) {
        commit('setUserInfo')
    },
    async requestUserProfile ({ dispatch, commit }) {
        await dispatch('requestUserInfo') // wait for `requestUserInfo` to finish
        commit('setUserProfile')
    }
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you misunderstood what mutations and actions for. Mutations can't be asynchronous and should modify state only. In contrast to them actions can be asynchronous, can request some data and after that can put these data to a state using mutations.

So all in all your code should look like this:

```
mutations: {
  setUserInfo (state, username) {
    state.requestUser = username
  },
  setUserProfile (state, profile) {
    state.profile = profile
  }
...
actions: {
  async requestUserInfo ({ commit }) {
     const data = await apiService("/api/user/")
     commit('setUserInfo', data["username"])
  },
  async requestUserProfile ({ dispatch, commit, state }) {
      await dispatch('requestUserInfo') // wait for `requestUserInfo` to finish
      let endpoint = "api/profile/";
      if (state.requestUser) {
        const data = await apiService(endpoint)
        commit('setUserProfile', data)
      }
  }
```